# Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Forbidden

Tags: jss

I have a JSS Tenant and Site working and Running. I created another Jss Tenant and JSS Site in it using Sitecore 9.3. Created a JSS App as I did before.

I created a new API Key for my second Site. Everything worked when I deployed it the first time. I got the site up and running. but then again when I tried to deploy its showing

```
Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Forbidden
 Body: Deployment not allowed; no secret set.
```

deployment secret is set, Graphql API is working as well. I can't find what the problem is. I even tried to use the first API key and again set up the JSS app to get a new deployment Secret but nothing worked. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's see a copy of your deploy secret config. Does the `name` attribute alongside your `deploymentSecret` attribute match the name of your new site? Could this be a copy paste issue somewhere? Have you tried using the `debugSecurity` functionality as outlined at the bottom of this page? https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/app-configuration

Comment: Thanks for your comment @marcel. yes it does match and I do have same `deployment Secret`  in both the places(app config and Sitecore site Settings). I did not try `debugSecurity` though. Will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this particular deployment issue. I created new SXA Tenant and site in the existing sitecore instance and I already had one SXA Tenant(app-name1), I created new JSS app and deployed. I also copied app-name2.config from \app-name2\sitecore\config to sitecore site folder JssDemosc.dev.local\App_Config\Include\zzz. Now I have 2 configs app-name1.config and app-name2.config, and they both have

```
<site>  and <javaScriptServices>
```

settings in them. now I could not deploy any of the Jss app. I deleted `<javaScriptServices>` from **app-name2.config** and deployment started working for both of them and files are being deployed in the correct locations.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the `Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Forbidden - 403` error with the Sitecore 10.x version when I was trying to deploy the JSS app. I followed the below steps to fix the same:

1. Validate the following files are being deployed to your website root folder(`<appname>.config` and `<appname>.deploysecret.config`.
2. In the website root folder, make sure `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config` are given with a valid path (template, layout, rendering).
3. In Sitecore, validate the "*deploymentSecret*" key settings from config are not conflicting.
   [image]
   [image]