# Unable to import JSS app to Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, jss

I’m trying to deploy JSS App on Sitecore, all seems to be in order but when I run this command

`jss deploy app -c -d` I am getting the following error

> Unexpected response from import service:
>
> Status message: Forbidden
>
> Body: Deployment not allowed; no secret set.

I have checked the file ****.deploysecret.config is created successfully and does contains

<app name="JSSAppNAme"
  `deploymentSecret="********************************"`  debugSecurity="false"
/>

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you deploy the config file first before deploying the JSS App?

Comment: For your error, please check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/25336/3035